# How do I load a (static nested) enum value from YAML fixtures in the Play Framework?

Tags: java, yaml, playframework, snakeyaml

```
public class Request extends Model {
    public static enum Category {
        First, Second, Third
    }
        public Category category;
}
```

I seem unable to properly create a Request with a Category in my YAML test fixtures / initial data. I've tried things like:

```
Request(areq):
    category: Request.Category.Third
```

And several other variations. Nothing really works. The [SnakeYAML page](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Enum) gives me some tantalizing hints but I don't see how to properly reference my app's packages. What is the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use just

```
...
category: Third
```

SnakeYAML should recognize type of category and convert Third string to Third value of Category enum during object construction.

Answer (score 1):

In Play1.2.x you can also use this form:

Fixtures:

```
EnumTest(enumtest01):
  status: ${models.EnumTest.Status.ACTIVE}

EnumTest(enumtest02):
  status: ${models.EnumTest.Status.DELETED}
```

For this model:

```
@Entity
public class EnumTest extends Model {

    public enum Status {
        ACTIVE, DELETED
    }

    public Status status;

}
```

Like you can use Groovy templates in the routes, and application.conf file, you can also use in the yml files.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not an experienced user, but I think Request is a bad name, because the class exists in the play-framework. So I would recommend to rename it. But for your problem it's not necessary. Use the complete name, meaning `models.Request.Category.Third`.

Comment: I agree with what you've said for the name "Request." This was just an example and not production code, but I should have watched out for that. In any case, this still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Hmm, I searched at the google group and found only one example. There was used `category: Third`. Which makes sense if the binding was done by the name. Don't forget the JPA-Annotation `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` at your category.